# i'm trying to access automate login using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

Here is my Last Attempt.. I'm Trying to connect with the webpage and then to the login using jsoup while doing it i'm facing error in passing user and pass.. here i found error but i'm not understanding where the problem is.. Kindly help me..!

Button ok;
    EditText user,pass;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ok= (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    user= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            trustEveryone();

            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://uogis.uog.edu.pk/Default.aspx?You%20are%20logout%20now.%20Please%20login%20again!")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            response = Jsoup.connect("https://uogis.uog.edu.pk/Default.aspx?You%20are%20logout%20now.%20Please%20login%20again!")
                    .data("txtLogin", user)
                    .data("txtPassword", pass)
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute(); 

            Document homePage = Jsoup.connect("https://uogis.uog.edu.pk/LandingPage.aspx")
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .get();




                System.out.print(homePage);


        }

    });
}
    public static void trustEveryone() {
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {


                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return true;
                }
            });

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }
            }}, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



}
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat information about the error?

Comment: it's not running due to error

Comment: And Error is found in this line .data("txtLogin", user)
                    .data("txtPassword", pass)